# Modeling A Head

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling a male head and I kinda fell into a bad situation wherein I mistakenly created unnecessary bumps in the surface. Is there a faster way to smoothen it to SKULL FACE without picking the VERTICES ONE BY ONE? thank you!

[image]

Comment: Firstly - I am kinda confused about what you are asking here. Secondly - Sculpt Mode?

Comment: you could try selecting the part you don't like, W > Smooth, and play with the values on the bottom of the Tools panel on the left of the 3D view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there are several ways to do it, here are some:

**1 -** Switch to *Sculpt* mode and use the *Smooth* brush.

**2 -** In *Edit* mode, select the faces and press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Smooth*, then play with the values on the bottom of the *Tools* panel.

**3 -** Select all the vertices and flatten then on the X or Y axis (depending on the orientation) with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. To create your own axis, select at least 3 vertices and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>spacebar</kbd>, you'll see the new axis in the *Transform Orientation* dropdown menu, keep it selected, select all the faces you want to flatten and <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>axis</kbd><kbd>axis</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

[image]

Comment: thank you very much :) that helped - sculpting